# LaTeX parenthesis problem with multline environment

Tags: math-mode, scaling, brackets

I have a problem with the different size of parenthesis with multiline (see image). Actually i don't care about the different size of the square parenthesis on `M` and `\bar{M}` but I really care about the round square one! I want the same size (and I don't wanna avoid `\left` and `\right` since I need the last parenthesis as big as the integral!). Some help?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\left\lbrace q\left( t\right) \right\rbrace = \left[ \Phi \right] \left( \left[ C\left( t\right) \right] \left[ \bar{M}\right] \left[ \Phi\right]^{\textrm{T}}  \left[ M\right] \left\lbrace q_{0} \right\rbrace + \left[ \Omega\right]^{-1} \left[ S\left( t\right) \right] \left[ \bar{M}\right] \left[ \Phi\right]^{\textrm{T}}  \left[ M\right] \left\lbrace \dot{q}_{0} \right\rbrace + \right. \\
\left. \left[ \bar{M}\right] \left[ \Omega\right]^{-1}  \intop_{0}^{t}  \left[ S\left( t-\tau \right) \right] \left[ \Phi\right]^{\textrm{T}}  \left\lbrace e \left( \tau\right) \right\rbrace d\tau  \right) .
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: ok, done now. sorry

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use

```
\left(    \right.  \\
\left.   \right)
```

as that doesn't match the sizes, use

```
\bigl(     \\
        \bigr)
```

or some other size such as `Bigg`

Answer (score 5):

You can place a `\vphantom` of the integral in the first line, as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\left\lbrace q\left( t\right) \right\rbrace = \left[ \Phi \right] \left( \left[ C\left( t\right) \right] \left[ \bar{M}\right] \left[ \Phi\right]^{\textrm{T}}  \left[ M\right] \left\lbrace q_{0} \right\rbrace + \left[ \Omega\right]^{-1} \left[ S\left( t\right) \right] \left[ \bar{M}\right] \left[ \Phi\right]^{\textrm{T}}  \left[ M\right] \left\lbrace \dot{q}_{0} \right\rbrace + 
\vphantom{\intop_{0}^{t} }\right. \\
\left. \left[ \bar{M}\right] \left[ \Omega\right]^{-1}  \intop_{0}^{t}  \left[ S\left( t-\tau \right) \right] \left[ \Phi\right]^{\textrm{T}}  \left\lbrace e \left( \tau\right) \right\rbrace d\tau  \right) .
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```