# Braces/parentheses don't display as expected

Tags: parentheses

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document} 
\Bigg\{ \big( \big( i,j \big) \big (i+1,j \big) \big) \\
\big(i,j\big)\big(i,j+1\big)\big)
\Bigg\}

\end{document}
```

after the opening brace the output goes to the next line and I don't understand why especially since this site

https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Brackets_and_Parentheses shows that this code

```
\big( \Big( \bigg( \Bigg(
```

should have the parentheses appearing on one line.

I even tried this [LaTeX parenthesis problem with multline environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168738/latex-parenthesis-problem-with-multline-environment)

doing this

```
\documentclass{article}   
\begin{document} 
\Biggl\{ \big( \big( i,j \big) \big (i+1,j \big) \big) \\
\big(i,j\big)\big(i,j+1\big)\big)
\Biggr\}
\end{document}
```

but that just caused errors.

with the exception of where I put "\\" I'm trying to get everything to appear on one line. Also the odd thing is that the closing parentheses and braces appear as expected on one line just not the opening ones.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  You want to go into math mode, don’t you?  So why don’t you do it?

Comment: all of these braces and brackets need to be in math mode.  just wrap the whole string in single `$` signs.  and you should really be using `\bigl`, `\bigr`, etc. to get the proper spacing.

Comment: using \[ and ]\ helped a lot but I want the \\ to still work. When I use $...$ it listens to the \\ but the two lines aren't aligned and using the l and r after the bigs doesn't make any difference. I also want the two Bigg braces to encompass the entire equation even though it's split into to lines.

Comment: I also tried this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46189/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-in-display-math-mode but it didn't work well with the math mode symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also want the two `Bigg` braces to encompass the entire equation even though it's split into two lines

You may want to think about using an `array` environment.

If, however, what you're actually trying to display is a column vector that's encased in curly braces, consider using a `Bmatrix` environment (requires the `amsmath` package). It'll typeset the vector more compactly than the `array`-based solution does.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document} 
\[
\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
\bigl( \bigl(i,j\bigr) \bigl(i+1,j\bigr) \bigr) \\[1ex]
\bigl( \bigl(i,j\bigr) \bigl(i,j+1\bigr) \bigr)
\end{array} \right\}
\]

\[
\begin{Bmatrix}
\bigl( (i,j) (i+1,j) \bigr) \\[1ex]
\bigl( (i,j) (i,j+1) \bigr)
\end{Bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

(Note that I've done away with the `\big` instructions for the "inner" pairs of parentheses in the second example.)